# ロジスティック回帰分析の考え方について

Tags: 機械学習

ロジスティック回帰分析の勉強をしているのですが、下記についてアドバイスいただけることがありましたらお願いできますと幸いです。

↓　↓

ロジスティック回帰分析の説明変数で、一般的に、発生(1)・非発生(0) に対して説明変数が線形的に変化する（例えば煙草をたくさん喫うほど肺がんが発生しやすい等）と思いますが、説明変数が発生（1）に対して非線形に変化する場合（例えば、年収と軽自動車購入・非購入など、年収100万円では軽自動車は買わないが、年収1000万円でも軽自動車は買わず、年収500万円で最も軽自動車購入の推定値が1に近づくような場合）は、単純にロジスティック回帰分析を実施し結果得られる標準偏回帰係数には意味があるのでしょうか？そして、その場合の標準偏回帰係数の解釈の仕方などあるのでしょうか？
また、発生・非発生の目的変数に対して、複数の説明変数が、上記のように非線形の場合、最も推定値が1に近づく説明変数の値を探索（年収がどれくらいなら最も軽自動車を購入する確率が高いか）したり、標準偏回帰係数のような各説明変数に重みづけを与えたりする方法はあるのでしょうか・・？

以上、お気づきの点がある方いらっしゃいましたら、コメントいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。